# Modify the binary search algorithm to make it work even on a list that is not sorted.

Tags: java, binary-search

Modify the binary search algorithm to make it work even on a list that is not sorted. It is better you create a new choice (case 6) in the main menu so your original binary search is kept. The new binary search method should have quite similar structure as the previous one except some logic changes.

Here is my original code:

```
// *****************************************************************
// IntegerListB.java
//
// Defines an IntegerList class with methods to create, fill,
// sort, and search in a list of integers. (Version B - for use
// in the binary search lab exercise)
//
// *****************************************************************
public class IntegerListB
{
    int[] list; //values in the list
    // ------------------------------------
    // Creates a list of the given size
    // ------------------------------------
    public IntegerListB (int size)
    {
        list = new int[size];
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    // Fills the array with integers between 1 and 100, inclusive
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void randomize()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
            list[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    }
    // ----------------------------------------
    // Prints array elements with indices
    // ----------------------------------------
    public void print()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ":\t" + list[i]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the index of the first occurrence of target in the list.
    // Returns -1 if target does not appear in the list.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    public int linearSearch(int target)
    {
        int location = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<list.length && location == -1; i++)
            if (list[i] == target)
                location = i;
        return location;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //Returns the index of an occurrence of target in the list, -1
    //if target does not appear in the list.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public int binarySearchRec(int target)
    {
        return binarySearchR (target, 0, list.length-1);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //Recursive implementation of the binary search algorithm.
    //If the list is sorted the index of an occurrence of the
    //target is returned (or -1 if the target is not in the list).
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    private int binarySearchR (int target, int lo, int hi)
    {
        int index;
        if ( hi < lo) // fill in the "not found" condition
            index = -1;
        else
        {
            int mid = (lo + hi)/2;
            if ( list[mid] == target) // found it!
                index = mid;
            else if (target < list[mid])
                // fill in the recursive call to search the first half
                // of the list
                index = binarySearchR(target, lo, mid-1);
            else
                // search the last half of the list
                index = binarySearchR(target, mid+1, hi);
        }
        return index;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Sorts the list into ascending order using the selection sort algorithm.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void selectionSort()
    {
        int minIndex;
        for (int i=0; i < list.length-1; i++)
        {
            //find smallest element in list starting at location i
            minIndex = i;
            for (int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++)
                if (list[j] < list[minIndex])
                    minIndex = j;
            //swap list[i] with smallest element
            int temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[minIndex];
            list[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
```

This is the driver class:

```
// ***************************************************************
// IntegerListBTest.java
//
// Provides a menu-driven tester for the IntegerList class.
// (Version B - for use with the binary search lab exerice)
//
// ***************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntegerListBTest
{
    static IntegerListB list = new IntegerListB (10);
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create a list, then repeatedly print the menu and do what the
    // user asks until they quit.
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        printMenu();
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        while (choice != 0)
        {
            dispatch(choice);
            printMenu();
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // Does what the menu item calls for.
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    public static void dispatch(int choice)
    {
        int loc;
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Bye!");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("How big should the list be?");
            int size = scan.nextInt();
            list = new IntegerListB(size);
            list.randomize();
            break;
        case 2:
            list.selectionSort();
            //invoke the sorting method in the IntegerListB class
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print("Enter the value to look for: ");
            loc = list.linearSearch(scan.nextInt());
            if (loc != -1)
                System.out.println("Found at location " + loc);
            else
                System.out.println("Not in list");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("Enter the value to look for: ");
            loc = list.binarySearchRec(scan.nextInt());
            if (loc != -1)
                System.out.println("Found at location " + loc);
            else
                System.out.println("Not in list");
            break;
        case 5:
            list.print();
            break;      
        default:
            System.out.println("Sorry, invalid choice");
        }
    }
    // ----------------------------
    // Prints the user's choices.
    // ----------------------------
    public static void printMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("\n Menu ");
        System.out.println(" ====");
        System.out.println("0: Quit");
        System.out.println("1: Create new list elements (** do this first!! **)");
        System.out.println("2: Sort the list using selection sort");
        System.out.println("3: Find an element in the list using linear search");
        System.out.println("4: Find an element in the list using binary search");
        System.out.println("5: Print the list");
        System.out.println("6: Find an element in the unsorted list using binary search");
        System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Binary search can't really work on an unsorted list. Its one of the preconditions. This might be asking for depth-first search though.

Comment: Someone deserves a special award if they figure this one out!

Comment: This is what the teacher asks for

Comment: You already have a method called `selectionSort` in your helper class.  I strongly suspect that you want "option 6" to sort the list first using that method and then pass it to the already existing binary search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary search needs to have the elements sorted by definition.

"In computer science, a binary search or half-interval search algorithm finds the position of a specified input value (the search "key") within an array sorted by key value."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm